# What does the signal of $y(n) = x(n^2)$ look like?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

The original signal is at *a)* in the image below, and I'm confused as to what the exponent on the dependent variable does to the signal, so can anyone point me to where I go wrong and how do I actually answer *b)*, which is $y(n) = x(n^2)$ ?

[image: sample answer I gave in the midterms]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y[n] = x[n^2]$$
Write it out:
\begin{align}
y[-3] = x[(-3)^2&] = x[9] = 0 \\
y[-2] = x[(-2)^2&] = x[4] = 0 \\
y[-1] = x[(-1)^2&] = x[1] = 1 \\
&\vdots \\
\end{align}

I'll leave to you to determine the final expression for $y[n]$ (fill in the "$?$")
$$y(n) = \left\{
\begin{align}
&1 \quad \text{?} \leq n \leq \text{?} \\
&0 \quad \text{elsewhere} \\
\end{align}\right. $$

Comment: so it's 1 only if it's in between -1 and 1, otherwise it's a 0?

Comment: @ITmaster correct

Comment: Your answer for *d)* is therefore also wrong, and you can probably now figure that out yourself ;) Hope that helped!

Comment: thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Jdip: how do you know what the value of, for example $y[2]$ is ? You assume it's zero, but I'm not sure how to justify it. Technically we have $y[2]$ = $x[\sqrt{2}]$ which is undefined.

Comment: @Hilmar Wouldn't that be $y[n] = x[\sqrt{n}]$ ? The ask is $y[n] = x[n^2]$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. I would argue that $y[2]$ is basically undefined and there isn't enough information to determine it. You could choose to make it 0. You could choose to determine it through bandlimited interpolation or assume the underlying time continuous rectangular signal and declare $y[n] = 1, 0 \leq n \leq 9$  All these method seems reasonable and defensible  but which one is correct?

Comment: I think I follow, but I'm still a little confused with what you're saying. The function isn't $y[n]=x[\sqrt{n}]$, it's $y[n]=x[n^2]$. So $y[2]=x[2^2]=x[4]$ which is defined, since $x[4]=0$. On the other hand, I agree that $x[2]$ does not map to any defined value of $y$, but one could argue that $y[\sqrt{2}]=x[2]=1$ (if we were to interpolate $y$). Is that what you're trying to say? Happy to take this to a chat.